# How to choose to which group new content will be visible?

Tags: nodes, organic-groups

I have a content type: Event. I put instances of Event inside the Calendar(everything works great). I also have Organic Groups installed and set up(I have a group called: employees).

Now, the problem is that when I create an Event I can't find dropdown list where I can choose to whom this content will be visible(to which group).

How to make it show up?

This is Drupal 7.

Comment: Did you install and enable the OG modules before or after you created the Event Content Type?

Comment: @Richard After, but I already solved the problem, there was bunch of new field types with no description so I had a luck by third try.

Answer (score 0):

One have to add a field to content type: `og_group_ref`.